# Is it correct using stack in my implementation?

Tags: c++, function, loops, data-structures, stack

```
#include <iostream> / File: int-stack.h /
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
const int BUFFER SIZE = 100;
class int stack
{
private:
int data[BUFFER SIZE]; // Use an array to store data
int top_index; // Start from 0; -1 when empty
public:
int stack(void); // Default constructor
bool empty(void) const; // Check if the stack is empty
bool full(void) const; // Check if the stack is full
int size(void) const; // Give the number of items currently stored
int top(void) const; // Retrieve the value of the top item
void push(int); // Add a new item to the top of the stack
void pop(void); // Remove the top item from the stack
void insert_at_bottom(int_stack& stack, int item); //adds a new item to the bottom of the stack if the stack is not full.
};
```

Given these function, and I need to implement a function called reverse_stack(int_stack& stack).
This is the suggest solution using recursion,

```
void reverse_stack(int_stack& stack)
{
if (stack.empty())
return; 
else
{
int top_item = stack.top();
stack.pop(); 
reverse_stack(stack); 
insert_at_bottom(stack, top_item); 
}
}
```

My solution is this, I wanted to know is it correct.

```
void reverse_stack(int_stack& stack){
  while(stack.empty() == false){
     insert_at_bottom(stack,stack.top());
     stack.pop();
}
```

Comment: This will run forever as you're always calling `insert_at_bottom` before `pop`ping, so the contents of the stack will constantly rotate. Also, there's a syntax error in your function.

Comment: You should write a test harness for your code so that you can test it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*No*, it is not.

---

Your function:

```
void reverse_stack(int_stack& stack){
  while(stack.empty() == false){
     insert_at_bottom(stack,stack.top());
     stack.pop();
}
```

you are missing a closing bracket in the loop, just after popping the stack.

> My solution is this, I wanted to know is it correct.

You should write some code which tests the function. One you see that it doesn't work, you should get a piece of paper and draw what your code does, that way you would *see* what is going wrong.

Your function does this (for a non empty stack):

```
---
|1|
---
|2|
---
|3|
---
```

Insert at bottom the top element:

```
---
|1|
---
|2|
---
|3|
---
|1|
---
```

Pop the top element:

```
---
|2|
---
|3|
---
|1|
---
```

Insert the top element at the bottom:

```
---
|2|
---
|3|
---
|1|
---
|2|
---
```

Pop the top element:

```
---
|3|
---
|1|
---
|2|
---
```

Insert top element at the bottom:

```
---
|3|
---
|1|
---
|2|
---
|3|
---
```

Pop tol element:

```
---
|1|
---
|2|
---
|3|
---
```

It was at this moment, your function knew it was wrong for sure! Your stack is exactly the same as before calling the function!

By the way, when will your function terminate? As it is written right now it will run an **infinite loop**!

Comment: A typo mistake, it should be int top_index;